# Sencha ExtJs5 Multiple models in one model and and one View

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm new to ExtJs , so not sure how to implement the below scenario.

I do have one form which have multiple sections and table. Each section fields are binding with one model variables.

Now i need to fetch the data from the java models and assign the data to fields. In Java the model structure is : Model A -> Model B, Model C, Model D.

Here, Model A is the main Model and Model B, Model C, Model D are the sub models to the main model.

The same structure need to apply in ExtJs View/Controller. Main form binding with Model A and all form sections are binding with Model B / C / D .

How can I work on this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to have models via the [Ext.data.model](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.Model.html) which then are hosted by the [Ext.data.store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.Store.html). You can setup the hierarchy as you need and then you just need to populate the store with the data.

Stores have various [proxies](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy.html) to get populated from different sources.

After that you provide stores to different components as data which bind to them and provide the UI.

Comment: I understand , store is component to call the java URL's . After fetching the data from store and assign to the Model, the model object have list of models. How can i use list of models to the sections in the view ?

Comment: Look at the UI components from ExtJs and see which one of them accepts store ... then just assign the store in the config section and the component should render your data. TreeView, Grid etc are store driven components.

Answer (score 0):

one cannot "fetch data from the Java models" ...use an ExtJS [Store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.Store.html) instead.